# using $resource in AngularJs to save array of objects

Tags: arrays, angularjs, resources, save

I am using `$resource` to retrieve data from the server using query.
The server returns an array of objects, which I store in *stuklijst*.
I can send the (updated) contents of *stuklijst* back to the server by looping through the array and using $save to send each item of the array back to the server.
I now want to send all items (the entire *stuklijst*) to the server in one go, without using the loop.

When trying a $save on *stuklijst*, Angular throws a "destination.push is not a function" error.
How can this be accomplished with `$resource`?

Here's the code:

Service:

```
var stukModule = angular.module('stuklijstServices', ['ngResource'])
stukModule.factory('Stuklijsten', function($resource){
 return $resource('rest/stuklijsten/:stuklijstID', {} );
});
```

Controller:

```
//Get the data from server      
  $scope.stuklijst = Stuklijsten.query({stuklijstID: $routeParams.stuklijstID});

//See below for sample of data returned by server
//Users can update the data and request a save using saveStuklijst

//Send them back to server (using saveStuklijst(Stuklijst))
  $scope.saveStuklijst = function(lijst) {
    //sending items from stuklijst one by one :
    for(var i = 0; i < lijst.length; i++) 
        {// console.log(i);
         // console.dir(lijst[i]);
          lijst[i].RowID = i
          f = new Stuklijsten(lijst[i]); 
          f.$save({stuklijstID: $routeParams.stuklijstID}); 
        } ;
    };
```

Data returned by server and stored in Stuklijst:

```
 [{"Name":"K FlxMT in DG met diameter 025 cm","LineType":0,"ProdID":"DG025KFLXMT","RowID":7,"Unit":"stk","Quantity":1},{"Name":"SPR Fl in DG met diameter 025 cm","LineType":0,"ProdID":"DG025SPRFL","RowID":8,"Unit":"stk","Quantity":1},{"Name":"T FlxFl in DG met diameter 025 cm","LineType":0,"ProdID":"DG025TFLXFL","RowID":9,"Unit":"stk","Quantity":0},{"Name":"VER PL EX in DG met diameter 025 cm","LineType":0,"ProdID":"DG025VERPLEX","RowID":10,"Unit":"stk","Quantity":0},{"Name":"K FlxMT in PV met diameter 008 cm","LineType":0,"ProdID":"PV008KFLXMT","RowID":11,"Unit":"stk","Quantity":0}]
```

Comment: Still did not find a way found to send back the array of arrays in one go to the server using $resource . After some further investigation I was able to do so using $http. However, in that case the beauty of using a REST service gets lost in the process...

Answer (score 7):

You can send an array of objects by re-defining your resource's `save` function to specify `isArray=true` like so:

```
stukModule.factory('Stuklijsten', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'rest/stuklijsten/:stuklijstID',
        {},
        {
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                isArray: true
            }
        }
    );
}]);
```

Then, in your controller, you can assemble the list and save all in one http request (less chatty API):

```
$scope.saveStuklijst = function(lijst) {
    var some_list = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < lijst.length; i++) {
        lijst[i].RowID = i
        f = new Stuklijsten(lijst[i]); 
        some_list.push({stuklijstID: $routeParams.stuklijstID}); 
    };
    Stuklijsten.save(some_list);
```

If you wanted to still be able to POST single objects, you could use the same concept to create a `saveBulk` function to preserve the original `save` for the single objects.