# $save gives me TypeError: undefined is not a function when saving model that is a list in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using current versions of asp.net, mvc, rest api, and angular.js. I populate my page with a list then on $save it gives me error **TypeError: undefined is not a function**

```
    $scope.scacTaskPLDetails = {};

    $scope.onGetTaskList = function () {
    var scacTaskRes = $resource("api/ScacTaskPLDetails");
    scacTaskRes.query({ taskID: scacTaskID }, function (scacTaskPL) {
        $scope.scacTaskPLDetails = scacTaskPL;
    });
}
 /************************ Save Task **************************/
$scope.onSaveScacTask = function () {
    if (!$scope.isEditing) {
        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-event');
        if ($scope.TaskForm.$invalid) { return; }
        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-event');
        if ($scope.TaskForm.$invalid) { return; }
    }

    $scope.scacTaskPLDetails.$save(function (results) {
        if (results.successful) {
            Notifications.success(results.serverMessage);
            $scope.onReloadPage();
        }
        else {
            Notifications.error(results.serverMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this is enough information. I have had no trouble up until now and the only thing different is that I am saving a list instead of a single object.  In debugging I can see the list of objects populating the viewmodel scacTaskPLDetails.

Comment: `$scope.scacTaskPLDetails` is an array of items. If you inspect them in your Dev Tools, you'll see that it's a collection of Resource instances, each one of which has $save method

Comment: Thanks, I can view the instances as I step through the save method and it contains my instances. This is why I am puzzled when I get the error Undefined: is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

you should use your resource to send an action to your endopint, not the response you got from the resource

try something like

```
var scacTaskRes = $resource("api/ScacTaskPLDetails");

  $scope.scacTaskRes.$save(function (results) {
        if (results.successful) {
            Notifications.success(results.serverMessage);
            $scope.onReloadPage();
        }
        else {
            Notifications.error(results.serverMessage);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I will try this on Monday, can't work from home. Is the reason to use resource to $save because I have a collection? Reason I ask is because the pattern I am using has always worked in this project until now but I have always only saved single viewmodel object instead of collection.

Comment: interesting I've never saw that approach, try to do it with the resource and let me know, good luck

Comment: Gave it a try several ways and still TypeError: undefined is not a function. We have been using resource to configure the call to the api then shove the result into our local viewmodel. With a single instance it works fine but with a collection...well no dice.

Comment: have you tried something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150544/using-resource-in-angularjs-to-save-array-of-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips. I finally got it to save my collections with isArray: true

```
app.factory("SaveArrayOfTaskPLObjects", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource(
    "api/ScacTaskPLDetails",
    {},
    {
        save: {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: true
        }
    }
);
```

}]);

Comment: yep, that why I sent you the link regarding the topic, I'm glad it worked, cheers!